# couldn't cast subtitle to chromecast devices in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-cast

I Used **Video streaming from google drive**:  E.x:  [Link Here](https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=6cab7cb4278cffe1&itag=22&source=webdrive&requiressl=yes&ttl=transient&pl=33&ei=O1M7WY_pKZLh-gPnir7IDA&mime=video%2Fmp4&lmt=1496395916737439&ip=2600%3A3c01%3A%3Af03c%3A91ff%3Afe60%3Acdb7&ipbits=0&expire=1497074555&sparams=api,ei,expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,ttl&signature=027E2A2DF78EA29BB2593BCED5D8BA94BD6FA704.609B7A6E4B9E40472BB8E1714BBDAE242C70F16B&api=AF4A92CAFE83CD24BEBCE98382E0A&cms_redirect=yes&mm=31&mn=sn-n4v7sn7z&ms=au&mt=1497060030&mv=m&key=cms1&app=storage)

( **The above url is playing well now, but when you see it maybe is Expired** )

> **The subtitles I used as:**

https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/tracks/GoogleIO-2014-CastingToTheFuture2-en.vtt

> **Result: couldn't cast video & subtitles It only work if I use video from**

https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/mp4/DesigningForGoogleCast.mp4

Answer (score 0):

For subtitles to work you need to enable CORS: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player#cors

You can configure this on the server that is hosting the subtitle files.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Leon Nicholls so much!!! It works well right now. Yeahhhhh

Comment: The subtitles has not play either with CORS. I've create a IOS sender app. Interestingly subtitles show rarely. Most of the time it's not display. It's display randomly. 
Is there any option to select subtitle in masterPlaylist for HLS files like side loaded subtitles in IOS sender framework?
I've use VTT file inside another m3u8 file where included in masterPlaylist.m3u8.
It doesn't make sense.